# jQuery SmoothDivScroll - Continuous scrolling without autoScroll?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, smooth-scrolling

Im using the jQuery SmoothDivScroll plugin. 
http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

I want to have continuous scrolling, but for manual scrolling not autoscroll. Can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can! 
Continuous manual scrolling using the hotspots or the mousewheel is built-in from version 1.2. Check it out at:

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com